# What would be a standard reference for the formula of the discriminant of $f(t^d)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, reference-request

For $f=a_0+a_1t+...+a_nt^n$, seems like
$$
\Delta(f(t^d))=(-1)^{n\frac{d(d-1)}2}d^{nd}(a_0a_n)^{d-1}\Delta(f)^d,
$$
where $\Delta$ is the discriminant.

Presumably this is not difficult to prove, but I just need a reference. Who did discover this formula for the first time?